# want to process files inside the folder subdirectories

Tags: php

How to process files inside the folder sub directories using php script.
Actually I want the image files inside each sub directories residing in my server itself to process and save to another location and save the folder name & file name in the database. Can anyone help and give a sample script on how to operate this...

the folder structure may be something like this

```
parent folder
 sub-folder1
   img1
   img2
   img3
   .
   .
   img'n'
 sub-folder2
   img1
   img2
   img3
   .
   .
   img'n'
 sub-folder3
   img1
   img2
   img3
   .
   .
   img'n'
 .
 .
 .
 sub-folder'n'
```

Also if on the process of copying and writing to database how can show a progress bar

Comment: you might want to try searching for each separate step instead of asking for someone to write a script for you. All of the steps have been answered on Stack Overflow before. The tasks involved are: recursively iterate over the filesystem, detect certain file types, move files in the filesystem, insert data to the database.

Comment: sorry, I accept a answer which I though would be help to customize to my need, the only thing left is that how to show a progress bar while the files are being processed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use this function to copy a folder including its subfolders from source to target.

```
function fullCopy( $source, $target ) {
    if ( is_dir( $source ) ) {
            $d = dir( $source );
            while ( FALSE !== ( $entry = $d->read() ) ) {
                    if ( $entry == '.' || $entry == '..' ) {
                            continue;
                    }
                    $Entry = $source . '/' . $entry; 
                    if ( is_dir( $Entry ) ) {
                            @mkdir( $Entry );
                            fullCopy( $Entry, $target . '/' . $entry );
                            continue;
                    }
                    copy( $Entry, $target . '/' . $entry );
            }

            $d->close();
    }else {
            copy( $source, $target );
    }
}
```

inside the loop u can execute a query to save file names to the database.

Comment: +1 if you include the "save the folder name & file name in the database" bit

Comment: here is a tutorial: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-v525/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This is described in detail at http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php. You can store files anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP glob()](http://us.php.net/glob) to gather your files. Saving info to the database is pretty straight forward. Moving the files can be done via [rename()](http://us.php.net/rename). The [MySQLi](http://us.php.net/mysqli) documentation is full of examples on how to talk to your database.